# Container App - Key vault as environment variables in azure pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to deploy container app from classic release pipeline.

I need to attach environment variables to container app and those environment value has to fetch from azure key vault. I have created azure key vault and authorised it in release pipeline.

Below are my two tasks in Ubuntu agent job of release pipeline.

1. Azure key vault
2. Azure container app deploy

In the second task of azure container app deploy, I am passing environment variables as below,

Server-id=$(server-id)

This $(server-id) is the secret name in azure key vault and this value has to fetch from vault.

During the pipeline job, secrets are downloaded successfully and container app also deployed with environment variables I mentioned.

After this, if I go to container app console, under environment variable I can clearly see the variable value of server-id.

In below image, container app environment variable are clearly seen.(for sharing purpose I made masked manually in the image )

[image: container app environment]

Also I tried other options environment variables as

1.Server-id=$(@Microsoft.Keyvault(SecureUri=https://test.azure.net/secrets/server-id))
2. Server-id=secretref:$(@Microsoft.Keyvault(SecureUri=https://test.azure.net/secrets/server-id))

Both options didn’t work as expected.

I want to use environment variables from azure key vault where it’s environment values should not visible under container app environment details.

Other options which I looked into secrets creation under container app in azure but unable to do this azure classic release pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. All details in environment variables are always visible in portal. For this purpose you should use secrets. And you can use [azure cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/containerapp/secret?view=azure-cli-latest) to set secret

```
az containerapp secret set -n MyContainerapp -g MyResourceGroup --secrets MySecretName1=MySecretValue1 MySecretName2=keyvaultref:https://example.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret,identityref:/subscriptions/sub/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/myidentity
```

Please notice the format used for secrets:

> A list of secret(s) for the container app. Space-separated values in 'key=value' or 'key=keyvaultref:keyvaulturl,identityref:identity' format (where 'key' cannot be longer than 20 characters).

Comment: Thanks for your response. As I mentioned I have already tried below options in environment variables of  Azure Container App Deploy in release pipeline as below,
Server-id=secretref:$(@Microsoft.Keyvault(SecureUri=https://test.azure.net/secrets/server-id))==> this throws error as ERROR: (ContainerAppSecretRefNotFound) SecretRef 'https://myvault.openai.azure.com/' defined for container 'myapp' not found.
Note : I have key vault configured in my pipeline task.

Comment: Additional information - I tried to set secrets from Azure console for my scenario as you mentioned and it is working as expected. I need to achieve the same from Azure Container Deploy pipeline where I am unable to set secrets to environment in pipeline. What I tried and its error message, I have attached in my previous response.

Comment: But you can use [Azure Cli task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-cli-v2?view=azure-pipelines) and use this command to set secrets in container apps. And you can do this from releases.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement this using Variable groups per environment and linking it to secrets from an Azure vault. link for more info
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried using variable group for environment as secrets and authorized key vault in my variable group as well and it was not working as expected

Comment: Detailed response -  I am using Azure Container App Deploy job in release pipeline and linked variable group from Azure Key Vault. Under environment variables of pipeline, i have given as below,
1.Server-id=$(server-id) => after deployment, under container app environment, those key vault secrets value are visible
2.Server-id=secretref:$(@Microsoft.Keyvault(SecureUri=https://test.azure.net/secrets/server-id))==> this throws as ERROR: (ContainerAppSecretRefNotFound) SecretRef '(@Microsoft.Keyvault(SecureUri=https://test.azure.net/secrets/server-id)' defined for container 'myapp' not found.